# NameError given after using input on python

Tags: python

This function is supposed to determine whether the user input is one of the viable (in this case, the strings "red", "yellow", and "blue" options, and if not ask for input again. However, upon typing in "yellow", it says NameError: name 'yellow' is not defined. Why does this happen?

```
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        init_choice = input("Give a primary color")
        if type(init_choice) == str:
            init_choice = init_choice.lower()
        if init_choice == "red" or init_choice == "yellow" or init_choice == "blue":
            valid = True
        if valid == False:
            print ("That is not a valid input.")
    return init_choice
```

Comment: It works fine for me as just one function.

Comment: Are you learning Python? If so why are you using Python 2? It hit end of life in January. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: @Tabulate -- That's because you are using python 3.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you are using `input`. Use `raw_input` instead. `raw_input` is what you have to use with python 2.